# Ogre Enforcer and Pyrohemia

Tags: magic-the-gathering

How do the cards [Ogre Enforcer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOgre%20Enforcer%5d) and [Pyrohemia](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPyrohemia%5d) interact if you activate Pyrohemia four times in one turn? My understanding is that the damage from multiple activations is considered to be a single source because it is the same permanent each time and hence would kill the ogre, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the ability specifically states that *Pyrohemia* deals the damage. So it's a single source dealing 4 damage and the Ogre dies.